# BottomSheetScaffold won't keep sheetPeekHeight when navigate back (Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, material3

According to [AndroidX Compose Material 3 example](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/material3/package-summary#BottomSheetScaffold(kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.Modifier,androidx.compose.material3.BottomSheetScaffoldState,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Shape,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,androidx.compose.ui.unit.Dp,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Boolean,kotlin.Function0,kotlin.Function1,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color,kotlin.Function1)), this `BottomSheetScaffold` has `peekHeight` = 128dp. At this time, it only has two `state`: `Expanded` and `PartiallyExpanded`. When I navigate to another screen then navigate back, the `BottomSheetScaffold` seem to lose its `peekHeight` and now it can be `Hidden`. I have my solution but it's not exactly what I want. How can I keep `peekHeight` in this situation?

Here is my code

```
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
@Composable
fun ScreenA(
    navController: NavController
) {
    val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        bottomSheetState = rememberStandardBottomSheetState(
            initialValue = SheetValue.Expanded,
            confirmValueChange = {
                it != SheetValue.Hidden  // Prevent collapsing but not what I want
            }
        )
    )

    BottomSheetScaffold(
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        sheetPeekHeight = 128.dp,
        sheetContent = {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(128.dp),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                Text("Swipe up to expand sheet")
            }
            Column(
                Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(64.dp),
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
            ) {
                Text("Sheet content")
                Spacer(Modifier.height(20.dp))
                Button(
                    onClick = {
                        navController.navigate("ScreenB") // navigate to another screen
                    }
                ) {
                    Text("Click to collapse sheet")
                }
            }
        }) { innerPadding ->
        Box(Modifier.padding(innerPadding)) {
            Text("Scaffold Content")
        }
    }
    LaunchedEffect(scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue) {
        println(scaffoldState.bottomSheetState.currentValue) // check scaffold state
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help:

```
 val scaffoldSheetState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
        SheetState(
            skipHiddenState = true,
            skipPartiallyExpanded = false,
            initialValue = SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded
        )
    )
```

From the docs: skipHiddenState - Whether the hidden state should be skipped. If true, the sheet will always expand to the Expanded state and move to the PartiallyExpanded if available, either programmatically or by user interaction.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue and it turns out that `skipHiddenState` doesn't recover when Activity is recreated.
I introduced a custom function instead of `rememberStandardBottomSheetState()` to save and restore the parameter.

```
@Composable
@ExperimentalMaterial3Api
fun rememberCustomBottomSheetState(
    skipPartiallyExpanded: Boolean = false,
    confirmValueChange: (SheetValue) -> Boolean = { true },
    initialValue: SheetValue = SheetValue.PartiallyExpanded,
    skipHiddenState: Boolean = true,
): SheetState {
    return rememberSaveable(
        skipPartiallyExpanded, skipHiddenState, confirmValueChange,
        saver = Saver(
            save = { it.currentValue },
            restore = { savedValue ->
                SheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded, savedValue, confirmValueChange, skipHiddenState)
            }
        )
    ) {
        SheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded, initialValue, confirmValueChange, skipHiddenState)
    }
}
```

The returned state can be passed to the scaffold state

```
val bottomSheetState = rememberCustomBottomSheetState()
val scaffoldState = rememberBottomSheetScaffoldState(
            bottomSheetState = bottomSheetState
)
```

I submitted the issue to the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/314796718). Probably it will be fixed in the future releases of Material3

Comment: Hey Max, do you encounter an issue about its expanded state? Because I have a similar problem, I set the initial value as `SheetValue.Expanded` but it starts with `SheetValue.HalfExpanded`.

Comment: @ilkeraslan The sheet restores previous state, not the initial one. 
So, if the initial state is SheetValue.Expanded and you change it to another state, then if Activity is recreated and the sheet is restored it takes the previous state, not the initial one.

If you want to restore the initial state you might need to pass `initialValue` instead of `savedValue` to `restore { }`